# Hashmap casting which is better

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Which way we should do casting first or second and why ?

first way ----------

```
Map mapDestinationSession=(HashMap)SessionUtils.getNamespacedAttribute(session, "mapDestinationSession", null);
```

second way ---------

```
Map mapDestinationSession=(Map)SessionUtils.getNamespacedAttribute(session, "mapDestinationSession", null);
```

Comment: They are two different things.

Comment: second way is better.

Comment: i have a object of hashmap in the session....so which way should be followed ?

Comment: @Shriram   Why it is better ?

Comment: because you don't have to know the implementation of your map

Answer (score 4):

I would go for the second option. You may change the type of your `Map` to `LinkedHashMap`, `ConcurrentHashMap`, `TreeMap`, `AbstractMap`. With the second solution, your change does not require a further code change. With the first option, because you cast to a concrete implementation, you will need to update your code.

Comment: okay so i directly can convert it into ConcurrentHashMap etc.. without creating a new object of ConcurrentHashMap  ...is it ?

Comment: By referring to it as `Map` you are allowed to use any of the subclasses of type `Map`. By referring to it as `HashMap`, you hugely limit the classes that you can use here.

Answer (score 0):

The second is better (you don't need to know what is the implementation of your Map).